# Why does the overhand knot jam but the figure-8 knot doesn't?

Tags: material-science, friction, elasticity, curvature

After tensioning a rope with an overhand knot in it, it is often very hard if not impossible to untie it; a figure-8 knot, on the other hand, still releases easily.

Why is that so? Most "knot and physics" literature seems more concerned with the *topology* of knots (see e.g. [here](http://www.volkerschatz.com/knots/knots.html)), but I suppose friction and elasticity of the rope play a role in knowing whether a knot jams or not.

I found [this reference](http://iopscience.iop.org/1367-2630/3/1/310/fulltext/) that explains why the overhand knot breaks earlier than the figure-8 — the former has a higher maximum curvature than the latter. Why doesn't this larger curvature make the overhand knot **easier** to untie? The knot would have more stored elastic energy that would aid overcoming friction when picking the knot apart.